# thread Что происходит при join?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-c++

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void fwriter(fstream &f) {
    f << " write ok"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    fstream f;
    f.open("log.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);

    thread th;

    th = thread(fwriter, ref(f));
    cout<<th.get_id()<<endl;
    th.join();
    cout<<th.get_id()<<endl;



    cout << "OK" << endl;
    getchar();

    return 0;

}
```

Вот такая программа есть соответственно поток после join не выполняется.

```
thread::id of a non-executing thread
```

Все ли ресурсы после этого освободил поток? 
Надо ещё что-то типо `th.swap(thread());` сделать?

Comment: Какие ресурсы вы имеете в виду? Которые могут быть захвачены в функции потока, или которые связаны с переменной потока? Первые в принципе освобождаются при корректном завершении функции, вторые - при выходе переменной из области видимости...

Comment: например exitcode или ещё что-то

Comment: Если нужен возврат из потока - то лучше `async`.

Comment: Что значит "все ли ресурсы освободил"? Сам объект `std::thread` - это "ресурс" или не "ресурс"? Ясно, что объект `std::thread` к этому моменту никуда не делся и в принципе не может никуда деться до конца блока.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После вызова `join()` объект потока перестаёт управлять потоком, как и при вызове `detach`. `get_id()` корректно возвращает пустой id - хотя это и не значит, что сам поток уничтожен окончательно, просто он не будет иметь видимых побочных эффектов.

После вызова `join()` переданный функциональный объект гарантированно выполнен, т.е. в вашем случае запись в файл завершена, и можно осуществить другую запись. Неизвестно, когда и как этот функциональный объект будут удалён, но в вашем случае он содержит только ссылки и не важно, когда они будут удалены - сам объект файла управляется корневым потоком.

В более сложных ситуациях нужно учитывать, что деструктор функционального объекта может быть вызван в другом потоке (иначе невозможно было бы реализовать `detach`), а значит ресурсы нужно захватывать либо по ссылке, чтобы они всегда уничтожались в корневом потоке, либо по значению - тогда не важно, в каком потоке они уничтожатся (но тут вполне можно выстрелить себе в ногу), либо через`shared_ptr`, который в данном случае схож с захватом по значению.